# "TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED" in UniswapV2

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, hardhat, uniswap

I have a problem using UniswapV2Router.sol .
I wrote a contract using UniswapV2Router Interface, and i create a function to use swapExactTokenForETH.

Here the code.

```
function swapForETH(
        uint amountInMax,
        uint amountOut,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to
    )external{
        IUniswapV2Router02(ROUTER).swapExactTokensForETH(
            amountInMax,
            amountOut,
            path,
            to,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

Now i wrote test where, first i made an approval for the ROUTER and then i try to swap some SAND Tokens in ETH.

Here for the code :

```
it("should swap exact tokens for ETH", async()=>{

        let ownerSandBalance  = await SAND_TOKEN.balanceOf(owner.address);
        console.log("Owner Sand Balance: ", (ownerSandBalance).toString());


        let tx = await SAND_TOKEN.connect(owner).approve(ROUTER, ownerSandBalance);
        await tx.wait();


        let approvance = await SAND_TOKEN.allowance(owner.address, ROUTER);
        console.log("Approval from owner to contract: ", (approvance).toString());


        let result = await contract.connect(owner).swapForETH(
            ownerSandBalance,
            "100000000000000000",
            [SAND, WETH],
            owner.address,
        );

        console.log("", (result[0] / decimals).toString());
        console.log("", (result[1] / decimals).toString());
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Now i don't understand why i get this Error, "TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED" .
ownerSandBalance is like 18576609770834064884363.
Can someone explain me why i get it?

Answer (score 0):

"100000000000000000" does not seem a uint. Did you try `web3.utils.toWei("0,1")` maybe ?